# Stop() not called after activity switch

Tags: android

Android activity life cycle ->
onCreate()->OnResume()->onPause()->Activity2_OnCreate()->Activity2_OnResume()->Activity1_OnStop()

While checking the flow via logs, OnStop of activity 1 is not called while switching to activity2. Is this phone specific as code runs fine i.e. onStop is being called on samsung note 2, coolpad. (So far tested) but not on MI note 3.

Answer (score 1):

When an activity is put to background `onStop` is not necessarily called, you should use `onPause` to determine if your activity is going to the background.

`onStop` will be called when you finish your activity.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html
Having a look at the mentioned references of the functions, it seems whenever activity goes to background . OnStop is called after [onPause()-1st activity + onResume-2nd activity]

Also refer to this.
http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/232-lesson-24-activity-lifecycle-example-about-changing-states-with-two-activities.html